# How to remove space between rows in .dat files using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-processing

I am dealing with a data file, which has only two columns:

```
 1 100
 2 200
 3 300
 4 400
 5 500

 6 600
 7 700
 8 800
 9 900
10 1000

11 1100
12 1200
13 1300
.
.
.
```

This file is in `.dat` format, which I loaded using the `np.loadtxt` method. I want to **remove the space** in between rows that are appearing **randomly**. I cannot do it manually because there are too many of them. So, I am wondering if I can use any method in python to perform this task.

Please give suggestions on it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use `pandas.read_csv()` with specific configurations.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("<your_dat_file>", delimiter=" ", header=None, skipinitialspace=True)
>>> df
     0     1
0    1   100
1    2   200
2    3   300
3    4   400
4    5   500
5    6   600
6    7   700
7    8   800
8    9   900
9   10  1000
10  11  1100
11  12  1200
12  13  1300
```

Comment: But it's not a .CSV format file. Does 'read_csv' works for loading the .dat files to?

Comment: Yes, I specified it as first argument

Answer (score 0):

I actually view this as a base Python problem, and so would suggest:

```py
import re

with open("data_file.txt", "r") as fin, open("data_file_out.txt", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        if re.search(r'\S', line):
            fout.write(line)
```

The file `data_file_out.txt` generated by the above should contain the sams contents as your current file, with empty lines removed ("empty" being defined here as lines which have either no content or only whitespace characters).

Comment: is there any way I can compare these empty space using if statment and then delete that empty row without generating new .txt file?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  But it is trivial to do a rename of the new file.

Comment: You could: 1) Read all lines into a string, 2) remove empty lines, and then 3) overwrite the original source file.